# Configuring SQL profiler

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-profiler

Is there a quickstart guide on how to configure SQL profiler for SQL 2005? I am using a shared database, so I want to only view queries that are executed by my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Trace Properties, '`Events Selection`' tab, there is a Button named '`Column Filters..`'
Click on this button launches a dialog where allows you to filter your profiling.

One of the filters is called `ApplicationName`.
Click on '`ApplicationName`' item on the left and you get right hand side pane with `Treeview Node` where you can type in the name of your application in the '`Like`' Node

Just found this documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by things like ApplicationName or LoginName

Trace Properties Events Selection tab Column Filters Button.